# Snowflake Node Query not showing Results

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to run a simple Snowflake query using Node.
Everything connects and seems ok but I can't seem to hook the Results of the query.
The code below is based on the official docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#)
This correctly logs the number of rows but can't log the actual results.
Unless i'm missing something the Docs don't show any object information.

Any ideas folks?

```
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
            
            var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
            account: 'xxx',
            username: 'xxx',
            password: 'xxx',
            database: 'xxx',
            warehouse: 'xxx',
            role: 'xxx'
            } );
            connection.connect( 
            function(err, conn) {
            if (err) {
            console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
            } 
            else {
            console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
            connection_ID = conn.getId();           
            var statement = connection.execute({
            sqlText: 'SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE LIMIT 1;',
            
            complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
            if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
            } else {
            console.log('Successfully executed statement: ' + stmt.getSqlText() + ' > ' + rows.length);
            }
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting the data to show in the terminal?

For example, instead of the SQL statement:

```js
console.log('Successfully executed statement: ' + stmt.getSqlText() + ' > ' + rows.length)
```

are you looking for:

```js
console.log(rows);
```

This is very basic and there are a lot of different ways to achieve what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.  The Snowflake documentation is meant to help get connected with Node and send some basic information, but I am sure your Node/JavaScript development team will be the main folks to code a client-side solution to complement your workflow.

Comment: Thanks Suzy. The issue I was experiencing was getting [Object Object] at the end of lthe log. If I just return "rows" then the data show ok. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems look ok , you missing some of the step after getting stmt in the else part, the below code will help you to get the result.

```
      var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
        
        var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
        account: 'xxx',
        username: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxx',
        warehouse: 'xxx',
        role: 'xxx'
        } );
        connection.connect( 
        function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
        console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
        } 
        else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
        connection_ID = conn.getId();
        query="select * from yourTable";
        dbConnection.execute({
                sqlText: query,
                streamResult: true,
                complete: function (error, stmt, rows) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    stmt.streamRows({
                        start: 0,
                        end: stmt.getNumRows() - 1,
                    })
                        .on('error', function (error) {
                            if (error) {
                                next({ statusCode: 400, message: error });
                            }
                            next({ statusCode: 400, message: 'Unable to consume requested rows' });
                        })
                        .on('data', function (row) {
                            output.push({ name: row.name })
                        })
                        .on('end', function () {
                        });
                }
            });
            }
```